# How to use zsh vcs_info with double quoted prompt?

Tags: shell, zsh, zshrc

this is my .zshrc file . vcs_info working for single quoted prompt but it's not working for double quoted prompt.

```
autoload -Uz vcs_info
zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git svn
zstyle ':vcs_info:git*' formats "- (%b) "
precmd() {
    vcs_info
}

setopt prompt_subst

# prompt='%2/ ${vcs_info_msg_0_}> '
prompt="%2/ ${vcs_info_msg_0_}> "
```

but this not working.

Answer (score 1):

you just need change your syntax to use vcs_info in double quoted prompts

```
prompt="%2/"'${vcs_info_msg_0_}>'
```

or here is another example (parrot os prompt)

```
prompt="%F{red}┌[%f%F{green}%n%f%F{yellow}㉿%f%F{cyan}%m%f%F{red}]─[%B%F{magenta}%~%f%F{red}]%f%F{201}"'${vcs_info_msg_0_}'"%f"$'\n'"%F{red}└╼%f%F{yellow}$%f"
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside double quotes, the parameter expansion is expanded immediately, so you are hard-coding the value of `${vcs_info_msg_0_}` *when the prompt string is defined*, rather than the value when the prompt is displayed.

Your options include

1. Continuing to use single quotes
2. Escaping the `$`: `prompt="%2/ \${vcs_info_msg_0_}> "`
3. Setting `prompt` itself inside `precmd`, so that `prompt` is freshly defined after each update to the VCS information.

   ```
    precmd () {
        vcs_info
        prompt="%2/ ${vcs_info_msg_0_}> " 
    }
   ```

Comment: That's what point 2 covers. Escape the `$` so that expansion is deferred until display time. (As an aside, why are you using `$USER` instead of `%n`?)